# How do I remove margin between flex children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

In the snippet below, I am trying to create a grid of records each of which has an image, details (heading and sub-details) and a button.

For the grid holding these records (which are added dynamically), I have used CSS grid to create an auto-fill grid with column dimension boundaries, while for the individual record items, I have used a flexbox with the direction set to `column` to make sure flex children flow from top to bottom with `space-between` them.

The problem I am having is evident in the attached snippet when the amount content of the details in one record on a row is greater than the others, those others become pushed down.

What I want is for the details to stay flush against the bottom of the image while the button remains at the bottom.

```css
.dashboard__main-content {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(5rem, 10rem));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;

}

.record {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 0.08rem solid #2a5583;
}

.record__image-holder {
  flex-basis: 45%;
}

.record__image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.record__details {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.record__title {
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
}

.record__more-btn {
  background: #2a5583;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.record__more-btn:hover,
.record__more-btn:focus {
  border: 0.01rem solid #2a5583;
  outline: none;
  color: #2a5583;
  background: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<section class="dashboard__main-content">
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">Stacks of cash in rubber wads</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/1">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">Sanother red-flag</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem isikator malagnur adip ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/2">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--intervention record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">need intervention</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet c sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="interventions/3">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--intervention record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">intervention Skope 2</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">doirkd dir djfkdj ejrkjks rioioid dfdkjkj eroppops dsdjrkjiojr jkjsj fjiepfis fjkdfjkjrso fsof stg-sa jkjd erridfjsk sitek er tkrj tejke wrw ewetie eeot ejfd eteroi reore tdg eret eoowieioiwe wwereerwer ...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="interventions/4">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--investigating">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">Another red-flag tester</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing doirkd dir djfkdj ejrkjks rioioid dfdkjkj eroppops dsdjrkjiojr jkjsj fjiepfis fjkdfjkjrso fsof stg-sa jkjd erridfjsk sitek er tkrj tejke wrw
        ewetie eeot ejfd eteroi reore tdg eret eoowieioiwe wwereerwer ...lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/5">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">some</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">s...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/6">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">where the government</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">In an effort to improve user privacy, MetaMask stopped exposing user accounts to dapps if "privacy mode" is enabled on November 2nd, 2018. Dapps should now call provider.enable() in order...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/7">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">where the government</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">In an effort to improve user privacy, MetaMask stopped exposing user accounts to dapps if "privacy mode" is enabled on November 2nd, 2018. Dapps should now call provider.enable() in order...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/8">View More</button>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: What is .record__image-holder's flex-basis for? If you remove it, the text will stay on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the children that don't grow `flex-grow:0;` and the one that grows: `flex-grow:1`

```css
.dashboard__main-content {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10rem, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  padding: 2rem;

}

.record {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 0.08rem solid #2a5583;
}

.record__image-holder {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.record__image-holder img {
  display: block;
}

.record__image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.record__details {
  padding: 0.7rem 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.record__title {
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
}

.record__more-btn {
  background: #2a5583;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  align-self: flex-end;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  float: right;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.record__more-btn:hover,
.record__more-btn:focus {
  border: 1px solid #2a5583;
  outline: none;
  color: #2a5583;
  background: aliceblue;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<section class="dashboard__main-content">
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">Stacks of cash in rubber wads</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet conse...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/1">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">Sanother red-flag</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem isikator malagnur adip ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/2">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--intervention record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">need intervention</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet c sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="interventions/3">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--intervention record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">intervention Skope 2</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">doirkd dir djfkdj ejrkjks rioioid dfdkjkj eroppops dsdjrkjiojr jkjsj fjiepfis fjkdfjkjrso fsof stg-sa jkjd erridfjsk sitek er tkrj tejke wrw ewetie eeot ejfd eteroi reore tdg eret eoowieioiwe wwereerwer ...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="interventions/4">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--investigating">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">Another red-flag tester</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing doirkd dir djfkdj ejrkjks rioioid dfdkjkj eroppops dsdjrkjiojr jkjsj fjiepfis fjkdfjkjrso fsof stg-sa jkjd erridfjsk sitek er tkrj tejke wrw
        ewetie eeot ejfd eteroi reore tdg eret eoowieioiwe wwereerwer ...lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adiscplicing lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/5">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">some</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">s...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/6">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">where the government</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">In an effort to improve user privacy, MetaMask stopped exposing user accounts to dapps if "privacy mode" is enabled on November 2nd, 2018. Dapps should now call provider.enable() in order...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/7">View More</button>
  </div>
  <div class="record record--red-flag record--draft">
    <div class="record__image-holder">
      <img class="record__image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/940365/pexels-photo-940365.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="crash site">
    </div>
    <div class="record__details">
      <h4 class="record__title">where the government</h4>
      <p class="record__comment">In an effort to improve user privacy, MetaMask stopped exposing user accounts to dapps if "privacy mode" is enabled on November 2nd, 2018. Dapps should now call provider.enable() in order...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="record__more-btn" record-path="red-flags/8">View More</button>
  </div>

</section>
```

Additional notes:

- to prevent your buttons from reflowing content when hovered, their `border-width` in both states has to be equal (make them `transparent` in normal state).
- it is almost never a good idea to provide a `border-width` value in anything else than `px` (and it should be an integer). Otherwise you'll see artifacts in browsers and your borders will flicker during animations, (not necessarily their animations).
- if you place a positive `fr` value in the `max` value of your repeating `grid-template-columns`, your elements will be equally distributed.

Comment: I used `rem` units on the `border-width`  because on the html rule, I explicitly set `font-size: 10px`, so I expect `.1rem` to be `1px`.  Will user stylesheets override the value I have set for `font-size` in the html selector?

Comment: @Oguntoye, Yes user stylesheets can set a new value of `font-size` on root element therefore changing `rem` value for the entire page (that's why we use `rem` in the first place). The question is: what do you want to happen to your border when `rem` value changes? Should your `1px` border change width and risk getting blurry during page animations?